# Patched font for devicons doesn't show up in terminal

Tags: terminal, plugin-devicons

I would like to install the Vim plugin "vim-devicons". But I am unable to install the patched font "Hack".

I copied the following [file](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/blob/master/patched-fonts/Hack/Regular/complete/Knack%20Regular%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete%20Mono.ttf) into `~/.local/shared/fonts`. The installation of the font seems okay to me because I am able to select it in Libre Office. But I can't choose it in the terminal. It won't show up.

After copying into `~/.local/shared/fonts` I ran the following command: `fc-cache -f -v`. Rebooted for the third time.

I am running Kubuntu 15.10 with the standard terminal (zsh).

Comment: I have my custom fonts (not devicons in particular) in `~/.fonts/` on Ubuntu 15.10. Perhaps try putting them there? I know the default path changed at some point from my Arch Linux days, but I don't know which paths Ubuntu 15.10 accepts (perhaps both?) It's worth a try anyway ;-)

Comment: I've always seen `~/.local/share/` for things using XDG paths, not `~/.local/shared/`. It looks like you might have an extra `d` character in the name of the directory you are using. `~/.local/share` is supposed to sort-of mirror `/usr/share`, and there is in fact an `/usr/share/fonts` on my system.  However, like Carpetsmoker, I have all my fonts ins `~/.fonts/` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I am running into the same problem on Ubuntu 18.10, and not sure what to do. I have the fonts installed in both `~/.local/share/fonts` and `~/.fonts`, but that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I can't vote to close here, but this has nothing to do with Vim. Try [SuperUser](https://superuser.com), or another Stack Exchange site for whatever OS you're using.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is not related to vi or vim.